# Visual Studio: Custom code highlighting based on regex

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

As my application supports some paranoid debug level (every data assignment, every step in the code is written to a log destination), my code is littered with logging calls in some methods, e.g.

```
logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, 0, "Initializing i18n...");
Lang.Language = SystemInfo.Language;
Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, 0, "Default system language: " + Lang.Language);
string[] languageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(ClientEnvironment.LanguagePath);
Logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, 0, "Initializing local language files...");
```

As you can see, there are only two "real" code lines. This makes the code somewhat hard to read. I wonder whether I can specify some custom code formatting rule within Visual Studio to let the logging lines appear in a soft gray text color, instead of the default text color. This would lead to an implicit highlighting of the "real" code lines, resulting in a more readable code.

I need something like:

```
If statement starts with "logger.Log", set foreground color to gray.
```

Do you know any plugins which could archieve such a behaviour?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: While i do not know of any extensions that offer this functionality, this page offers information on how to develop such an extension yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166778(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853826/colorize-knockoutjs-comment-bindings-in-code-editor?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: This is not an appropriate answer to the poster's question, but I cannot delete it because StackOverflow won't allow the accepted answer to be deleted.

This Visual Studio extension will do just what you want:

- [VSColorOutput - A Visual Studio extension to colorize your build and debug output](http://mike-ward.net/vscoloroutput)

You can specify regular expressions for custom output window colorization.

Comment: OP was asking about syntax highlighting in Visual Studio's editor. "VSColorOutput can change the color of a line emitted to the output window based on specified rules. "

Comment: @JeffreyKnight Right you are.  However, StackOverflow won't let me delete the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

**altrue.CustomColoring** extension allows to set custom foreground color based on simple regular expressions. Restart Vs Code after installing it, it won't work correctly without restart.

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=altrue.CustomColoring

Comment: this extension doesn't support regex

Comment: This extension supports Regex:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight