# Colorize knockoutjs comment bindings in code editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, syntax-highlighting, code-editor

A project I'm working on makes extensive use of knockout comment bindings.

In the code editor, these are difficult to summarily differentiate from standard comments in the markup.

[image]

Is there any way that one might be able to make knockout comment bindings appear in a different color?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255042/visual-studio-custom-code-highlighting-based-on-regex).  (Sorry, rereading the accepted answer doesn't help here.  Question itself is similar though)

Comment: [Off site, and probably overkill](https://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/writing-a-brightscript-syntax-highlight-extension-for-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Was just looking into writing an Editor Classifier extension... Thanks

Comment: If you get that far and you'd like to share, I'm sure my team could make use of it.  I hadn't even thought of it being a problem until this post, but yes - it would help a lot

Comment: @JamesThorpe https://github.com/biggyspender/knockoutjsCommentBindingHighlighter-

Comment: Great - I'll take a look at it tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a solution, I coded an editor classifier Visual Studio extension to change the color of knockoutjs comment bindings in documents with HTML content types:

[image]

https://github.com/biggyspender/knockoutjsCommentBindingHighlighter-

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/add2efac-979c-4cac-8e7b-d2a477e15276

Comment: Just trying it out - I installed it from the VS Gallery to VS2013, do I need to do anything to enable it?  I see the new option for colours in tools->options->fonts and colors, but it doesn't seem to be colouring the code.  I also have resharper installed, if that might make a difference?

Comment: Oh dear. Works fine on both mine and colleagues machines. All contributions welcome!

Comment: ok!  Will dig a bit deeper and do some debugging when I get a chance - will see you on github then - SO isn't the place for this now :)